# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isEventFrom' of undefined at NgbDropdown._isEventFromToggle

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I've build ng-bootstrap modal, which works with problems, but it works at least. but whenever I open the website (doesn't matter which page) on each click the error comes in: [image]

I tried to comment all the added ng-bootstrap modal code all over the project, but the error still remains. I don't even know where the problem comes from. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you please add the a code snippet of what seems to be causing this?

Comment: Read here for possible solutions https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2343

Comment: @PierreDuc Thanks! I did look into that yesterday, but couldn't find anything useful, But now I looked in once again and one of the solutions seems to be working for me !

Comment: @Mavinter alright :) good to hear